# Netty: Closing a client's connection on exception

Tags: java, netty

So I have a UDP server, and when I get an exception I want to close the connection to the client.  So in my Handler I have the following:

```
@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ExceptionEvent e) throws Exception {
    logger.error("Error received while processing message.", e.getCause());
    e.getChannel().close(); // this is bad mojo
}
```

However, this will close the server socket and the server stops accepting new connections.  But `e.getChannel().getRemoteAddress()` returns `null` in that method.  So how do I close the connection to the client without shutting down the whole server?

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP server socket (you are talking about Datagram Sockets, right?). UDP is a connectionless protocol, hence no client connection to close.